# is there issue will stringstream.str().c_str()?

Tags: c++, stringstream

For Code:

```
stringstream ss("012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789");
```

some articles said it is wrong for followed usage due to ss.str return temp object and will destructered before call .c_str();

```
 const char* cstr2 = ss.str().c_str();
```

but I run the example, there is no problem? how to understand?

Comment: Can you link the articles, please?

Comment: For example, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/20883180/420683

Comment: That's a dup, actually. _[edit: oh, no, not quite. nearly!]_

Comment: It would be better if you explained what sort of "problem" you expected, then we can tell you why you didn't encounter it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Why shouldn't it be a dup? `stringstream::str()` *does* return a `std::string` (copy/object)

Comment: @dyp: Yes and that means the answer is the same, but it does _not_ mean the question is the same.

Comment: I'm going to go with duplicate. Both are "in theory this doesn't work but it certainly seems to work"

Answer (score 13):

> But I run the example, there is no problem?

Technically there's nothing *immediately* wrong in the expression:

```
const char* cstr2 = ss.str().c_str();
```

The temporary (copy) object returned by `ss.str()` will live long enough to let you get the underlying c-string with `c_str()`.

**However, the result is likely a dangling pointer**: by the end of the expression, the string object will probably be destroyed already, so the underlying memory may be deallocated (this depends heavily on the `std::basic_string` implementation).

Therefore, this approach should be avoided since it's impossible to safely use the resulting pointer. What you should do instead is:

```
auto x = ss.str();
const char* cstr2 = x.c_str();
```

The above code won't get you any trouble, since the returned value of `str()` is now being copied/is not a temporary anymore, and the access to `x.c_str()` will give you a valid pointer.

Comment: Your answer: "There's nothing wrong. There's probably something wrong. Here's how to make your code not wrong any more."

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, my answer "There's nothing wrong in this expression. But the result of the expression is a problem: here's how to fix it".

Comment: I suppose if you'd only quoted the expression I'd agree. But you quoted the whole _statement_, and the _statement_ is not okay because it's (a) useless and (b) dangerous :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit That's why I used the word "*expression*" in "there's nothing wrong in the expression".

Answer (score 6):

Yet another wonderful C++ landmine.

Basically, your pointer references a block of memory (C string) that is referencing a temporary copy (string) of whatever was in the stream at the time you did the double affectation.

str() returns a temporary object.

Life expectancy of temporary objects is rather short. Either someone takes a reference to them immediately (e.g. `string& s = ss.str()`) or they die at the end of the statement they were born in.

However, the compiler allows to get a reference to the same block of memory through c_str(), but indirectly, so it flies under the compiler's radar. What a pity.

So your pointer will indeed be valid at the time c_str gets it, but just for about as long as if you did something like this in plain old C:

```
const char * cstr2;
{
    char ss_str[100];            // str() return value is dynamically created
    char * c_str = &ss_str_[10]; // c_str() takes a reference to some part of it
    cstr2 = c_str;               // cstr2 takes an indirect reference to str() ret. val.
}                                // compiler pulls the plug on str() ret. val.
```

So, right after the end of this very statement, c_str is already referencing the cadaver of whatever string str() returned.

Now since temporary objects are allocated on the stack, you may well never notice the problem. Object deallocation in itself will likely not modify the defunct string value, but as soon as the compiler will reuse this bit of stack, the [proverbial guru](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guru_Meditation) will have something to meditate over.

Comment: It looks like the "this bit of IBM lore" link is useless now. It gets automatically redirected to the IBM knowledge center without any reference to the original page/article.

Comment: ah well, that's web reliability for you... :)

Comment: You can not take a reference of the string, you actually have to copy the returned object! The reference will become invalid at the end of the function call due to the exact same reasons as why you can't use the returned value of `c_str()`.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, it's important to understand that attempting to make use of a dangling pointer is not *guaranteed* to fail in any obvious way. It can appear to "work" just as often as it can crash spectacularly.

Secondly, yes, that code is invalid and you shouldn't do it. The stringstream's lifetime is not important because `std::stringstream::str()` returns *by value* (i.e. a *copy* of the internal buffer), but then you're still subject to that string going out of scope before you can make use of its C-string pointer.

Comment: I think it worthwhile to point out that in a slightly modified context the code is legit
MessageBox(..., const char*);
MessageBox(..., stream.str().c_str());