# stringstream and multithreading

Tags: c++, multithreading, ofstream, ostringstream

I'm new to multithreading and C++ and I'm having a problem when trying to use threads in my application which save files. The code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

void writeCSV(vector<vector<double> > & vec, const char* filename) {

    ofstream output(filename);

    for (vector<vector<double> >::const_iterator i = vec.begin(); i != vec.end(); ++i) {
        for (vector<double>::const_iterator j = i->begin(); j != --i->end(); ++j) {
            output << *j << ", ";
        }
        output << *(--i->end()) << "\n";
    }


}

void testFn(int id) {
    std::ostringstream filename;
    vector<vector<double> > v(460, vector<double>(460,0));
    filename << "test" << id << ".csv";
    const char* fileStr = filename.str().c_str();
    cout << id << " : " << fileStr << endl;
    writeCSV(v, fileStr);

}


int main() {

    int numOfThreads = 180;
    std::thread t[numOfThreads];


    for (int i= 0; i< numOfThreads; i++) {
        t[i] = std::thread (testFn, i);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i< numOfThreads; i++) {
        t[i].join();
    }

    return 0;

}
```

When I run this program, it prints out in the terminal (subsection of results):

```
66 : 0�c
97 : test97.csv
90 : �'�ǳ
85 : �'�ǳ
43 : 
9695 : �'�ǳ
67 : �'�ǳ
93 : 
 : �_   ��
115 : test115.csv
144 : test144.csv
99 : test99.c0
68 : 
91 :  )�
98 : test98.c0
```

as well as saving the files with weird/wrong filenames. This seems to be an issue from multithreading and ostringstream I guess, but any ideas why/how to fix?

Comment: Sounds like data race.

Comment: No, it is not a data race. Speculation rarely leads to the right answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21034834/is-there-issue-will-stringstream-str-c-str

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This has nothing to do with multithreading.

```
const char* fileStr = filename.str().c_str();
```

`std::ostringstream`'s `str()` method returns a `std::string` representing the contents of the string stream.

A `std::string`'s `c_str()` method returns an internal pointer to the string data.

What you're missing is that the pointer returned by `c_str()` is only valid until either the `std::string` is modified, or it is destroyed, whichever comes first.

Here `std::string` gets destroyed immediately, because it is a temporary value. As such, a pointer to its internal data is immediately invalidated.

You must store the returned string in an object, that exists as long as the string data is needed. Simply:

```
std::string str = filename.str();
const char* fileStr = str.c_str();
```

`str` continues to exist for the remainder of its automatic scope, which is long enough, here.

Answer (score 5):

In your file initiialisation code, you have the following excerpt:

```
std::ostringstream filename;
...
filename << "test" << id << ".csv";
const char* fileStr = filename.str().c_str();
```

That final line is a **killer**. What you're doing is taking your hard-earned `filename`, getting the `string` representation from it, extracting the `c_str()` pointer from it - and then ***destroying*** the temporary `string` object. From that point on, any attempt to access `fileStr` is fraught.

What you need to do is assign the temporary `string` object to a local variable:

```
filename << "test" << id << ".csv";
std::string fileString = filename.str();
const char* fileStr = fileString.c_str();
```

That guarantees the lifetime of the temporary `string` object - at least until the end of the function!

Without doing that, `fileStr` points into the middle of the unallocated heap - and the heap changes underneath it.